# How can I add new method in Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm new to Swagger API so does in ASP.Net, I would like to know if how can I add new HTTP methods(e.g. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) on the UI. It only contains 6 methods as a default. I would like to add like another GET method. So, any help?

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DemoSwagger.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Cat", "Dog", "Bear" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id, string sm, string BCID)
        {
            if (id == 1)
            {
                return "Cat";
            }
            else if (id == 2)
            {
                return "Dog";
            }
            else if (id == 3)
            {
                return "Bear";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Out of Range";
            }    
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {


        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {

        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like ? We can't answer with so few informations.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hopes it makes clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger just represents your API "signature". You don't add a method to Swagger, you add a method to your API, and Swagger shows it.

You can just add methods to your API and they should show up. If they don't, decorate them with `[Get]` and/or `[HttpGet]` (depending on your version of Swagger and MVC API).

Comment: I edited one line of code in the WebApiConfig.cs and then I just put [HttpGet]/[HttpPost] on my controller and then I'm now able to add new methods. At first , I thought there has something to do with swagger.. Thank you this helps alot

Comment: If it solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted :) Also, you could edit your question to provide the solution you've found (for the WebApiConfig).

Comment: @JeraBalais What line did you add to your WebApiConfig.cs ?